# vs code cant run and debug web api .net 5

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, swagger

I just created a new project.

"dotnet new webapi -n Play.Catalog.Service --framework net5.0"

I click on run and debug in vs code and I get a 404 error. I open the project in normal VS and it works.

In visual studio i get this URL when I run the project: https://localhost:44321/swagger/index.html (works)

In Vs code i get: https://localhost:5001/ (doesn't work)

here is my launch setting in vs code: `"Play.Catalog.Service": { "commandName": "Project", "dotnetRunMessages": "true", "launchBrowser": true, "launchUrl": "swagger", "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000", "environmentVariables": { "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development" } }`

How do I fix this issue? I want to be able to run the project from VS code. I have made no changes to the code other than when vs code suggested a new build file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that my URL was wrong vs code doesn't lunch with the correct URL.

Correct URL:

`https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html`

To make vscode launch with the correct URL add the below code in the lunch.json

```
"uriFormat": "%s/swagger/index.html"
```

Example:

```
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/{your own project root}",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/{your own project root}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)",
            "uriFormat": "%s/swagger/index.html"
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach"
    }
```

Got this answer from github: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9038#issuecomment-1380871802